# Gradient is not working in i - e 7,8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to show my background as a gradient but it is not working properly here is my code

```
.content1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    margin-top: -30px;
    background:filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0px, OffY=0px, Color=#666666);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0px, OffY=0px, Color=#666666)";
    background: -webkit-gradient(center,0 0,41,0 0,0, from(#D06494), to(#401246));
    background:-webkit-radial-gradient(0% 0%, ellipse cover, #D06494 0%, #401246 41%); 
    background:-moz-radial-gradient(0% 0%, ellipse cover, #D06494 0%, #401246 41%); 
    background:-o-radial-gradient(0% 0%, ellipse cover, #D06494 0%, #401246 41%); 
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(0% 0%, ellipse cover, #D06494 0%, #401246 41%); radial-gradient(ellipse at 0% 0%, #D06494 0%, #401246 41%);
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 25px 40px 50px;
}
```

Please help me, what to do ?

Comment: I'd leave IE<9 users without gradient... If it's a mandatory part of the layout structure, you can always use a background image instead.

Answer (score 0):

for **IE6-9** use **filter** not -ms-filter:

```
.content1 {
    /* IE7, IE8, IE9 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#D06494', endColorstr='#401246',GradientType=0 ); 
}
```